# foreach and query display laravel

Tags: foreach, laravel, laravel-4

I have a table with join, and group by, so i have multiple item in the table like:

```
namecat   nameprod
1         a
1         b
1         c
2         a
2         a
2         c
```

I want to display in a select drop down menu, Since is a result from a query that i have in the $products variable, I passed the it to my view

```
return View::make('admin.view')->with('products',$products);
```

Then in my admin.view

```
@foreach ($products as $product)


{{Form::select('categorie', array(

$product-namecat => array($product->nameprod => $product-nomeprod)))
}}
@endforeach
```

like this i just get a lot of drop down for each category i have. how can i do to have a drop down menu with title in bold with namecat e.g. (1) and then all the product in 1. like this in laravel docs:

```
Generating A Grouped List

echo Form::select('animal', array(
    'Cats' => array('leopard' => 'Leopard'),
    'Dogs' => array('spaniel' => 'Spaniel'),
));
```

I try to use 2 foreach:

```
   @foreach ($products as $product)
@foreach ($product->namecat as $category)


    {{Form::select('categorie', array(

    $category => array($product->nameprod => $product-nomeprod)))
    }}
    @endforeach
 @endforeach
```

but it says Trying to get property of non-object (BTW i saw someone using that kind of build inside a foreach but there's no way i can $product->namecat work inside a foreach it says Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  Why?)

Actually I have in mind (in a normal programming way) something like:

```
    echo Form::select('animal', array(
foreach ($product->nomecat as $cat)
        $cat => array( foreach ($product->nameprod as $prod)
                               $prod => $prod
                       endforeach),

     endforeach));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume your **$products** array looks something like

`$products = [
  (object) ['namecat' => 1, 'nameprod' => 'a'],
  (object) ['namecat' => 1, 'nameprod' => 'b'],
  (object) ['namecat' => 2, 'nameprod' => 'a'],
  (object) ['namecat' => 2, 'nameprod' => 'b'],
  // ...
]`

for a grouped list with that **$products** array to work, you'd need some tweaking. an easy way would be bringing a new variable **$categories** into the game, that you can fill in your controller for instance.

`$categories = [];
foreach ($products as $product) {
  if (!isset($categories[$product->namecat])) {
    $categories[$product->namecat] = [];
  }
  array_push($categories[$product->namecat], $product->nameprod);
}
View::make('leView')->with('categories' => $categories);`

**within the view:**

so since $categories looks like this:

`$categories[1] => ['a', 'b']
$categories[2] => ['a', 'b']`

you should be able to use the [Form::select](http://laravel.com/docs/html#drop-down-lists)

`{{ Form::select('category', $categories) }}`

Comment: added the view example